# Change order of Orion response

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm calling orion with a Geo-location filter, like this one:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/queryContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "entities": [
  {
    "type": "City",
    "isPattern": "true",
    "id": ".*"
  }
  ],
  "restriction": {
    "scopes": [
    {
      "type" : "FIWARE::Location",
      "value" : {
        "circle": {
          "centerLatitude": "40.418889",
          "centerLongitude": "-3.691944",
          "radius": "13500"
        }
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
EOF
```

I read on the fiware orion documentation that the returned entities are returned by increasing entity/registration creation time. Like is explained [here](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Pagination)

There is the possibility to change this behaviour?

Comment: Originally posted at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1246, authored by Daniel Gonzàlez Lareo

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order is not possible in NGSIv1, but in [NGSIv2](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/) it has been taken into account. Have a look to [this issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1103) in the fiware-orion repository in order to monitor the implementation status of the feature.

**EDIT:** since Orion 0.28.0 you can use the `orderBy` URL parameter to change this behaviour, both in NGSIv1 (see [this piece of documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/pagination/index.html#ordering-results)) and NGSIv2 (see "Ordering results" section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/)).

Comment: You can add a +1 comment in https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1103 in order to show your support to the feature.

Comment: Answer has been updated with information regarding Orion 0.28.0 (to be released soon).